# css/less background icons positioned left and centered

Tags: html, css

hi i am trying create something similar on a smaller scale to say font-awesome where my with my own icons.

i have three icons:

```
sell.png (20px x 20px)
buy.png (20px x 20px)
cma.png (20px x 20px)
```

my goal is to have the background image be to the left and vertically aligned middle to the text.

this is what i have so far, but if it was working, well... I wouldn't be here!

```
<span class="amls amls-buy">buy</span>
<span class="amls amls-sell">sell</span>
<span class="amls amls-cma">cma</span>
```

css:

```
.amls {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    :before {
        background-repeat: none;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; top: 2px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;    
    }
}

.amls-buy:before {
    background-image: url('img/buy.png')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it and set your icon as the background image for your span (not the :before) with `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-size: auto 100%;` to fit it to your span. Keep the padding on the span so the icon is sitting inside the padding.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo3nz25b/). :)